# Does this TV cable need to be rehung in a proper manner?

Tags: outdoor, cables, internet

The company cable installer loosely hung cable on these tree branches to cross a public road rather than using poles or at least affixing the cable to the trees themselves.

Do I need to have them come back out to install poles and proper attachments, or can I attach these to the tree trunks myself? I assume poles are necessary but am not sure.

[image: cable strung over tree broken branch]

[image: cable strung loosely nover tree branch]

Comment: Attach them to trees? That's never ok, for several reasons. From your comments you probably should have just called them first. This sounds like a temporary setup.

Comment: Quite sure your roads department will want to have a talk with the cable guy also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes.

You need to call the cable company to have them fix this.

#### No.

You should not attempt to fix it yourself - they may end up blaming you for the work.

---

Whether they choose to install poles, bury the cable or do something else, it should be on them to get it done properly.

Answer (score 5):

The cable company would normally only do this to get service to a customer quickly since the job to set poles or bury the cable would take time for permitting and would follow up later. It could also be a temporary line while they repaired the main line.

Call the company and get them to explain what the situation it. You do not want to do anything with those cables, they are not your property.

Comment: Agree this looks like a temp run.  Usually they come back out in a week or three and to a perm install.